# SQL take just the numeric values from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the follow data in a column:

```
aud_344266_jayde_adams
int_343581_jtou_s5_ep1
of_344289_geordie_s21_rig_c
soft_343726_24hrpc_s4_norbiton
on_334195_sas_s5_1007_1008
```

and I only want to return the following:

```
344266
343581
344289
343726
334195
```

As you can tell there is a pattern in the number I want to return. They have to underscore before and after them and also have a length of 6 characters.

Is there any way of doing this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example data, this works:

```
select left(stuff(t.col, 1, patindex('%[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%', t.col), ''), 6)
```

Or even more simply:

```
select substring(t.col, patindex('%[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%', t.col) + 1, 6)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=660be8f400ba9ade4c76e55b643031e9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I just would have made the patindex a bit more specific   patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',col)   +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Or `'%[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%'` since the OP states that there must be underscores around the value. Your pattern could find a match in a string of more than 6 digits.

Comment: @HABO I thought the same afterwards, but I missed my EDIT window  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I totally agree with you and HABO.  I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: Amazing! thanks so much for your help guys. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @user9167864 You should accept the answer was helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use left, right and charindex function

example:

```
declare @row as varchar(100) = 'aud_344266_jayde_adams'

select @row,  right(@row, len(@row)-charindex('_',@row)), left(right(@row, len(@row)-charindex('_',@row)),-1 + charindex('_',right(@row, len(@row)-charindex('_',@row))))
```

For your table you do:

```
select left(right(_Column, len(_Column)-charindex('_',_Column)),-1 + charindex('_',right(_Column, len(_Column)-charindex('_',_Column))))
From Tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

`APPLY` is your friend.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (SomeString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @yourtable (SomeString) VALUES 
  ('aud_344266_jayde_adams'),('int_343581_jtou_s5_ep1'),('of_344289_geordie_s21_rig_c'),
    ('soft_343726_24hrpc_s4_norbiton'),('on_334195_sas_s5_1007_1008');

-- Solution
SELECT      TheNumber = SUBSTRING(t.SomeString,d1.Pos,d2.Pos-d1.Pos)
FROM        @yourtable AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',t.SomeString)+1))      AS d1(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',t.SomeString,d1.Pos))) AS d2(Pos);
```

**Returns:**

```
TheNumber
----------
344266
343581
344289
343726
334195
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SUBSTRING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) combine with [CHARINDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp) to achieve it

```
select substring(value, CHARINDEX('_', value) + 1, 6)
from TempTable
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77a20ee68cf9a4828a24b71d83b51b43)

**Output**

```
344266
343581
344289
343726
334195
```

Comment: @user9167864 You should accept the answer was helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers